# Fieldset border is missing in iphone6 plus

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I am working on the responsive part of my website, and in iPhone 6 plus, fieldset borders are missing(both portrait and landscape mode).

I checked fieldset elements on other responsive site(w3schools) on iPhone 6 plus,
In portrait mode i can see border but it disappears in landscape mode.

For all the devices (iPhone and iPad):
fieldset border disappears, as soon as I zoom in.

If I remove legend, border will appear again (in all the cases).

Please provide some pointers

Answer (score 0):

Try using div mimicking fieldset instead of HTML fieldset:

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldset">
    <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fieldset
{
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-top: 1em;
width: 500px;
}

.fieldset h1
{
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
}

.fieldset h1 span
{
display: inline;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: #fff;
padding: 5px 10px;
position: relative;
top: -1.3em;
}
```